# How can I narrow down the cause of corrupted file path?

Tags: 20.04, ram, swap, nvme

Currently I'm facing weird issues under my Ubuntu 20.04 during training my deep learning model using a python script. Seemingly randomly, I face seg-faults or weird errors where the file path name gets corrupted and looks like this :

```
File "/home/hossein/pytorch-image-models/timm/data/parsers/parser_image_folder.py", line 58, in __getitem__
      return open(path, 'rb'), target
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/hossein/SSD_IMG/ImageNet_DktaSet/txain/n01\x0819313/n01819313U7072.JPMG'
```

The correct filename is : `/media/hossein/SSD_IMG/ImageNet_DataSet/train/n01819313/n01819313_7072.JPEG`
This seems to only happen when I use more than 8 workers(like 20 threads) and it only takes about 12~13 minutes to error out like this(it completes one round of all training data, and only at the second round, errors out in the middle).
I have plenty of RAM around 32GB, and as much for the swap, and swappiness is set at 10.
Most of my RAM and swap space is empty when these kinds of errors happen, so I'm not sure if thats a memory issue(like RAM is 19/32 and swap is 4/32), but it looks like a memory issue! to me so I ran some tests like memtest for 6+ hours successfully, followed by 2 hours of Aida64 Cache and memory tests.
NVME drive is a `Samsung 980 1tb` and HDD sentinel and CrystalDisk both show 100% health without any issues.(the partition in question is ext4 by the way)

How can I identify and eliminate the cause of this? Is there an app that I can use to simulate multi-threaded IO workload and see if my NVME is at fault under this workload, or if its the hardware issue if so what exactly is it RAM/CPU/MB?